# is random interval with 0.9 confidence level same as 90% confidence interval?

Tags: confidence-interval

I am confused with these 2 terms.
I have now considered that they are the same. Actually, am I correct?

Comment: I think it would be quite unlikely for someone to be discussing a 0.9% confidence interval, so this probably refers to 90%. As always, context matters though.

Answer (score 1):

"Percent" means "per 100". Therefore, $90\% = \frac{90}{100}=0.9$.

I say those two terms are the same, even if the former is non-standard terminology.

Comment: That's just what I would have said, too.